# how to iterate over random range in python and count results

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am new to programming and I am trying to create a random number iterator that will take in a numpy random range and count how many times each individual number from 1-10 appears.

Example:
random range goes from 1 to 5 and it will count how many times the #s appear. count1 appears once, count2 appears 3 times and count 9 appears once.

code:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.random(10)


count1 = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0
count4 = 0
count5 = 0
count6 = 0
count7 = 0
count8 = 0
count9 = 0 
count10 = 0

for x in range(1,x1): 
  if x == 1:
    count1 += count1
  elif x == 2:
    count2 += count2
  elif x == 3:
    count3 += count3
  elif x == 4:
    count4 += count4
  elif x == 5:
    count5 += count5
  elif x == 6:
    count6 += count6
  elif x == 7:
    count7 += count7
  elif x == 8:
    count8 += count8
  elif x == 9:
    count9 += count9
  elif x == 10:
    count10 += count10
    
 print(count1)
 print(count2)
 print(count3)
 print(count4)
 print(count5)
 print(count6)
 print(count7)
 print(count8)
 print(count9)
 print(count10)
```

Comment: Your print statements shouldn't be indented inside the `elif`

Comment: I changed it and I get this: 
 
"for x in range(1,x1):

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Comment: would you want to count 12 as an occurrence of 1 and 2? or just one occurrence of 12? what are the constraints of the range?

Comment: x1 is not a python int but a numpy.int32. They behave differently, thats why you can't `range(x1)` without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has "countX += countX" and both of those are zero - so you are always just adding zeroes together.  You want "countX += 1".

For your print, use print(str(countX)) and make sure that is not indented (not sure if above is just formatting)

But beyond that I do not think this code is achieving what you are looking for.  Your are simply picking a number between one and 10, then looping from 1 to one less than that number and tallying.  So for example if your random number was a 5, your results would be:
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0.

You want to define how many times you will run the loop and randomize the number each time within your loop